# Send mass email with phpmailer where email body is the result of sql query in a html table

Tags: php, html, sql, sql-server, phpmailer

I will try to explain what I need to do as best as I can:

I have this remote SQL database, where are stored thousand os records and tables;
I connected succesfully to this database with php and sqlsrv module.

The query I run is this:

```
$sql = "SELECT [FOURNI], [NU_INT], [NU_IMM], [NOM_EQP], [N_SERI], [TYP_MOD], [MARQUE], [NOM_UF], [NOM_ETAB], [DA_AP], [OBSERV], [OBSERV2], [INT_CM], [LIB_STATUT] FROM [INPROGRESS_WO_VIEW]
        WHERE [FOURNI] <> 'NULL'
        ORDER BY [FOURNI] ASC, [NU_INT] ASC";
```

and this is the result:

[query result table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VAh6.png)

I also set up phpmailer and have been able so send email to selected adresses;

What I need to do:

Send an email for every [FOURNI] (1st column) in the query with a HTML table in the email body that return all the rows for that specific [FOURNI] (in the posted picture the column head is "Fornitore")

Most [FOURNI] have more than one rows associated and you can't predict how many;
I have been able to associate the email address of every [FOURNI] in a different query, taking the parameter from a different table and using a LEFT JOIN.

I will need to be able to use variables and put them, for example, in the subject, like so:

```
$sub = "TEST EMAIL TO THIS  " . $fourni;
```

Where $fourni is the result of a query that return the data of that single row,
for example:

```
$sql = "SELECT [FOURNI] FROM [INPROGRESS_WO_VIEW]
        WHERE [FOURNI] = 'GAMBRO'";
```

I'm sorry if this is too confusing, I will try to clarify as much as I can.

I'm using WAMP on windows 10 32bit - php 5.6.19 // remote database is SQL SERVER 2008 R2 on Windows server 2008

Thank you

**EDIT 30/08/2016:**

Thanks to @Synchro, I tried the mailinglist file in the example files of phpmailer, searched for hours,[found something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24436694/sending-dynamic-table-in-phpmailer?rq=1), and I've come up with this code, but when I run it it just loads the page undefinitely:

```
//connection details and query
    $serverName = "**********"; //serverName\instanceName
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"******", "UID"=>"*****", "PWD"=>"*****");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

    if( $conn ) {
         echo "Connection established.<br />";
    }else{
         echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
         die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

    $sql = "SELECT [FOURNI], [NU_INT], [NU_IMM], [NOM_EQP], [N_SERI], [TYP_MOD], [MARQUE], [NOM_UF], [NOM_ETAB], [DA_AP], [OBSERV], [OBSERV2], [INT_CM], [LIB_STATUT] FROM [INPROGRESS_WO_VIEW]
            WHERE [FOURNI] = <> 'NULL'
            ORDER BY [NU_INT] ASC";


    $sql2 = "SELECT DISTINCT FOURNI, AD_EMAIL FROM FOURNIS2
             WHERE FOURNI = 'BARBAGALLO'
             ORDER BY FOURNI";

    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
    if( $stmt === false ) {
         die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

    $stmt2 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql2);
    if( $stmt2 === false ) {
         die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

//here begins the mailing list

error_reporting(E_STRICT | E_ALL);

date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');

require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtps.aruba.it';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->Username = '*****';
$mail->Password = '*****';
$mail->setFrom('*****');

$mail->Subject = "PHPMailer Simple database mailing list test";

include "sql.php";
$result = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt2, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($result as $row) { 
    $mail->addAddress($result["AD_EMAIL"], $result["FOURNI"]);    

    while ($result = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt2, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $fornitore = $result['FOURNI'];
    }
    $body = "<table><tr><th>ODL</th><th>INV</th><th>APP.</th><th>SERIALE</th><th>MODELLO</th><th>MARCA</th></tr>";

    while($row2 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $body .= "<tr><td>".$row2['NU_INT']."</td><td>".$row2['NU_IMM']."</td><td>".$row2['NOM_EQP']."</td><td>".$row2['N_SERI']."</td><td>".$row2['TYP_MOD']."</td><td>".$row2['MARQUE']."</td></tr>"; 
}

$mail->Body = $body.'</table>';
$mail->set('X-Priority', '3'); //Priority 1 = High, 3 = Normal, 5 = low
$mail->Send();    
    // Clear all addresses and attachments for next loop
    $mail->clearAddresses();
if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
}
?>
```

From this example,I have a mailing list $sql2 made up of two columns: FOURNI, AD_MAIL
From this table run the first foreach that should substitute the email address to the addAddress field;

For every email that I send I need to create a dynamically generated html table from the table $sql, that return all the rows associated with the column FOURNI (first column in both tables) in the table $sql2.

I've tried a hundred different ways with many errors, but I'm not able to figure out the proper algorithm to write the code.

Comment: Look at the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer. It does basically what you ask.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction; I had a look at it and does send an email for every contact in the table;
The problem is that I need to send a different email for every contact, where the content is the result of a sql query displayed in a HTML table.
The two sql tables have in common one column: [FOURNI], that will also be recipient name

Comment: I figured it out, answering my own question, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39281483/create-dynamic-html-table-from-sql-query-result-to-use-for-mailing-list-with-php).