# Create dynamic html table from sql query result to use for mailing list with phpmailer

Tags: php, database, loops, logic, phpmailer

following my [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39190457/send-mass-email-with-phpmailer-where-email-body-is-the-result-of-sql-query-in-a), I try to rephrase it to make it more clear:

I have this [two tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huhMt.jpg) that are the result of two queries ;

The tables have the first column in common but  each row in the first table can have more than one correspondence in the second.

I need to iterate through each row in the first table and create a dynamic html table with all the correspondent row(s) from the second.

This is the code I tried but it only gives as result the first row from the second table:

`$stmt2` is for table1 and `$stmt` is for table2

```
$row2 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt2, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($row2 as $fornitori) {
    $fornitore = $row2['FOURNI'];

    //Intestazione della tabella uguale per tutti

    echo "<table><tr><th>ODL</th><th>INV</th><th>APP.</th><th>SERIALE</th><th>MODELLO</th><th>MARCA</th></tr>";
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        if ($fornitore == $row['FOURNI']) {
                echo "<tr><td>".$row['NU_INT']."</td><td>".$row['NU_IMM']."</td><td>".$row['NOM_EQP']."</td><td>".$row['N_SERI']."</td><td>".$row['TYP_MOD']."</td><td>".$row['MARQUE']."</td></tr>";
            }
        }
    }
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

These are the two queries:

1 - `$sql` that goes to `$stmt`

```
$sql = "SELECT [NU_INT],[NU_IMM],[N_SERI],[NOM_EQP],[TYP_MOD],[MARQUE],NOM_UF],[NOM_ETAB],[DA_AP],[OBSERV],[OBSERV2],[LIB_STATUT], A.FOURNI, AD_EMAIL    
FROM [INPROGRESS_WO_VIEW] A    
LEFT JOIN    
FOURNIS2 F    
ON A.FOURNI = F.FOURNI    
WHERE A.FOURNI <> 'NULL'    
ORDER BY A.FOURNI ASC";
```

2 - `$sql2` that goes to `stmt2`:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT DISTINCT A.FOURNI
FROM FOURNIS2 A
LEFT JOIN 
[INPROGRESS_WO_VIEW] B
ON A.FOURNI = B.FOURNI
WHERE [NU_INT] <> 'NULL'
ORDER BY A.FOURNI";
```

I need to to this because I need to send an email to every row in the first table with the information of the second with phpmailer

I hope I've been more precise and clear this time :)

Thank you

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with mailing anything - that's just what you'll do once you've figured out how to generate your text correctly. I'm not familiar with SQL server, but I'd guess that you need to execute the second query while you're inside the outer loop, otherwise you'll only ever get the first set of results in the inner loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question because after hours of trying I figured out the logic and what was wrong.

This is how I was able to connect the two tables, basically  I had to insert in the second query a variable that stored the result from the first, like this:

```
// TABLE 1 QUERY
$sql2 = "SELECT DISTINCT A.FOURNI
FROM FOURNIS2 A
LEFT JOIN 
[INPROGRESS_WO_VIEW] B
ON A.FOURNI = B.FOURNI
WHERE [NU_INT] <> 'NULL'
ORDER BY A.FOURNI";
// WE MAKE THE RESOURCE FOR TABLE2
$stmt2 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql2);
if( $stmt2 === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
// INIZIAMO IL WHILE A PARTIRE DALLO $STMT2
while ($row2 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt2, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {            
            $sql = "SELECT [NU_INT],[NU_IMM],[N_SERI],[NOM_EQP],[TYP_MOD],[MARQUE],[NOM_UF],
            [NOM_ETAB],[DA_AP],[OBSERV],[OBSERV2],[LIB_STATUT], A.FOURNI, AD_EMAIL
            FROM [INPROGRESS_WO_VIEW] A
            LEFT JOIN
            FOURNIS2 F
            ON A.FOURNI = F.FOURNI
            WHERE A.FOURNI = " . "'" . $row2["FOURNI"] . "'" . // HERE WE ASSIGN THE VARIABLE FROM TABLE1, SO THE TWO HAVE A CORRESPONDENCE
            " ORDER BY A.FOURNI ASC";
```

After that I figured how to send an email for every element in table1 with the correspondent result from table2:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_STRICT | E_ALL);

date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');

require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;



$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = '*********';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true; // SMTP connection will not close after each email sent, reduces SMTP overhead
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl"; //This is important, I forgot this parameter the first time and it didn't send any email, just stuck in a loop
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->Username = '*******';
$mail->Password = '*******';
$mail->setFrom('******');
$mail->addReplyTo('******');




// DATI CONNESSIONE DATABASE
$serverName = "******"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"******", "UID"=>"******", "PWD"=>"******");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
// CONTROLLA SE LA CONNESSIONE AVVIENE CON SUCCESSO
if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

// QUERY CON ELENCO FORNITORI CHE HANNO ATTIVO UNO O PIU' INTERVENTI IN CORSO
$sql2 = "SELECT DISTINCT A.FOURNI
FROM FOURNIS2 A
LEFT JOIN 
[INPROGRESS_WO_VIEW] B
ON A.FOURNI = B.FOURNI
WHERE [NU_INT] <> 'NULL'
ORDER BY A.FOURNI";
// CREIAMO LA RISORSA A CUI POI ATTINGERA' IL PRIMO WHILE
$stmt2 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql2);
if( $stmt2 === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
// INIZIAMO IL WHILE A PARTIRE DALLO $STMT2
while ($row2 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt2, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            // IMPOSTIAMO LA SECONDA QUERY $SQL ED ASSEGNIAMO IL FORNITORE A QUELLO CORRISPONDENTE NEL PRIMO WHILE
            $sql = "SELECT [NU_INT],[NU_IMM],[N_SERI],[NOM_EQP],[TYP_MOD],[MARQUE],[NOM_UF],
            [NOM_ETAB],[DA_AP],[OBSERV],[OBSERV2],[LIB_STATUT], A.FOURNI, AD_EMAIL
            FROM [INPROGRESS_WO_VIEW] A
            LEFT JOIN
            FOURNIS2 F
            ON A.FOURNI = F.FOURNI
            WHERE A.FOURNI = " . "'" . $row2["FOURNI"] . "'" . //ASSEGNIAMO LA VARIBILE FORNITORE
            " ORDER BY A.FOURNI ASC";

            $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
            $mail->Subject = "URGENTISSIMO: SOLLECITO INVIO RT CHIUSURA INTERVENTI APERTI - " . $row2["FOURNI"];

            // HEADER TABELLA UGUALE PER TUTTI
            $body = "<html><head><style>
                     table, tr, td, th {
                        border: solid 1px;
                     }
                     th {
                        background-color: yellow;
                     }
                     </style>
                     </head>
                     <body>                      
                     <table><tr><th>ODL</th><th>INV</th><th>APP.</th><th>SERIALE</th><th>MODELLO</th><th>MARCA</th><th>PROBL.</th><th>JOB</th><th>DATA RICH.</th><th>REPARTO</th><th>PRESIDIO</th></tr>";

            while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {

                $body .= "<tr><td>".$row["NU_INT"]."</td><td>".$row["NU_IMM"]."</td><td>".$row["NOM_EQP"]."</td><td>".$row["N_SERI"]."</td><td>".$row["TYP_MOD"]."</td><td>".$row["MARQUE"]."</td><td>".$row["OBSERV"]."</td><td>".$row["OBSERV2"] . "</td><td>".$row["DA_AP"]. "</td><td>".$row["NOM_UF"]. "</td><td>".$row["NOM_ETAB"]."</td></tr>";
                $mail->addAddress($row["AD_EMAIL"]);
            }

            $body .= "</table>                        
                      </body>";

            $mail->msgHTML($body);

            if(!$mail->send()) {
                echo 'Message could not be sent. <br />';
                echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo . "<br />";
                } else {
                    echo 'Message has been sent';
                    }
}

?>
```